# RxJava repeat with delay only part of the flow

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2, repeat

I have an Rx flow which performs two actions in sequence whenever a certain event happens:

1. send an SMS to a given set of numbers - which returns `Single<Holster>`
2. save the event on a local DB - which returns `Completable`

here is my code

```
private void saveBluetoothAlarm(@NonNull Alarm alarm, int type) {
    disposable.add( dbManager.getHolsterDAO().getCurrentHolster()
        .map(holsters -> holsters.get(0))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap(holster -> sendSmsToAll(holster, alarm.type))
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMapCompletable(holster -> {
            switch (alarm.type) {
                case StatisticsEventType.EXTRACTION:
                    if (something)
                        return Completable.complete();
                    else
                        return Completable.fromAction(() -> dbManager.getAlarmDAO().insert(alarm))
                                .andThen(saveAlarmOnServer(holster.getId(), alarm));
                case StatisticsEventType.MOVEMENT:
                    if (somethingMore)
                        return Completable.complete();
                    else
                        return Completable.fromAction(() -> dbManager.getAlarmDAO().insert(alarm))
                                .andThen(saveAlarmOnServer(holster.getId(), alarm));
            }
            return Completable.complete();
        })
        .subscribe(() -> {}, Timber::e)
    );
}
```

everything works, now I need the first action `sendSmsToAll(holster, alarm.type)` to be repeated a defined amount of times, each delayed by a defined amount of seconds, these settings are defined in my `Holster` object.

I tried editing to the `flatMap()` like the following, making `sendSmsToAll()` return `Holster`:

```
.flatMapObservable(holster -> Observable.just(sendSmsToAll(holster, alarm.type))
            .repeat(holster.sms_settings.repetitions_count)
            .delaySubscription(holster.sms_settings.interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
)
```

but the SMS is sent only once, I even tried a lot of other "combinations" (mostly because I am a noob with RxJava) but nothing works.

Comment: I think you should use Observable.from() instead of Observable.just() because .just emits one single emission.

Comment: @The_Martian - I have tried `Observable.fromCallable()` because I don't have `Observable.from()` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that:

```
.flatMapObservable(holster -> Observable.zip(Observable.defer(() -> sendSmsToAll(holster, alarm.type)),
                                             Flowable.timer(holster.sms_settings.interval, SECONDS),
                                             (x, y) -> x)
                                        .repeat(holster.sms_settings.repetitions_count))
```

?